# Firebase authentication not working in NuxtJs application

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, nuxtjs3

In am using Firebase Authentication in my Nuxt App. I am following the Firebase Documentation for setting up Authentication using GoogleAuthProvider. In my case, onAuthStateChanged() listener returns null even after successfull redirect.

When the user enter my web application, Nuxt will execute the plugin in the client side. There the firebase configuration is initialized. Then the initUser() function defined in useFirebaseAuth.ts composable is called. If user successfully logged In, log the user details.

Note : After I encountered this error, I replaced signInWithRedirect to signInWithPopup, it works very well.

```js
// plugins/firebase.client.ts
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initUser } from "~~/composables/useFirebaseAuth";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {

    const config = useRuntimeConfig();
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        databaseURL: "...",
        projectId: "...",
        appId: "...",
        messagingSenderId: "...",

    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    initUser(firebaseApp);
})
```

```js
// composables/useFirebaseAuth.ts
import { FirebaseApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth,signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithRedirect, signOut, User } from "firebase/auth";
import { equalTo, getDatabase, onValue, orderByChild, query, ref as dbRef } from "firebase/database";

export const signInUser = async () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    const auth = getAuth();
    await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)

}


export const initUser = async (firebaseApp: FirebaseApp) => {
    const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
    const db = getDatabase()

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {

        if (user) {
            console.log(user)
        } else {
            console.log("user not logged in"
            return navigateTo('/login')

        }
    });
}


export const signOutUser = async () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    await signOut(auth)
}
```

In the above code, I always get the user value as null. I am working on the project for 2 months. The authentication works fine almost one month ago. But it is not working now. Please help me to resolve the issue.

```bash
# node --version
v19.5.0


# npm version
{
  npm: '9.3.1',
  node: '19.5.0',
  v8: '10.8.168.25-node.11',
  uv: '1.44.2',
  zlib: '1.2.13',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.18.1',
  modules: '111',
  nghttp2: '1.51.0',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '8.1.0',
  uvwasi: '0.0.14',
  acorn: '8.8.1',
  simdutf: '3.1.0',
  undici: '5.14.0',
  openssl: '3.0.7+quic',
  cldr: '42.0',
  icu: '72.1',
  tz: '2022g',
  unicode: '15.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.8.1',
  nghttp3: '0.7.0'
}
```

I have gone through many answers posted for same question in the stackoverflow website. But those answers didn't solved my issues.

Comment: The small code snippets do not help. Can you please share the complete component file so we can try to reproduce it?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I edited my code snippet. I hope now it looks clear.. I think there is a bug in signInWithRedirect method in firebase auth. Kindly help me.

Comment: @RagulR did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Onyoursix I haven't found any solution. I think there is a bug in signInWithRedirect function